# Array of procedures inside a class pointing to class method

Tags: delphi, class, pointers, methods, procedure

I have a class (TExample) and I want to have an array of pointers that point to TExample methods. For example, I'd like to have TExample.ThinkOne and do aPointers[1] := @TExample.ThinkOne or something similar. How can I properly do this? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to prefix your questions with `[DELPHI]`. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
type
  TProcType = procedure(const AParm: Integer) of object; // Method type
  TProcArray = array of TProcType; // Dynamic array 
  TExample = class
  public
    procedure A(const AParm: Integer); // Method signature matches TProcType
    procedure B(const AParm: Integer);
  end;

var
  pa : TProcArray;

procedure Init(const AExample: TExample);
begin
  SetLength(pa, 2);
  pa[0] := AExample.A;
  pa[1] := AExample.B;
end;
```

Comment: How could I modify this so that instead of an array, I add the methods to a StringList using AddObject so that I could associate a searchable string with each one. I then want to pass in a command string and execute the method that matches the string.

Comment: @kbriggs, you could add a function pointer to a stringlist or you could create a wrapper object. But it is maybe cleaner to use a TDictionary.

Comment: when I try this: Commands.AddObject('Alpha',@AExample.A) I get "variable required" compiler error.

Comment: I created a separate question to show my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779258/adding-object-methods-to-a-stringlist-so-they-can-be-invoked-by-name